# Slow netatalk authentication / connectio speed

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, afp, netatalk

i have a netatalk server running on ubuntu server 10.04.1. connecting and moving files works generally, but, when connecting / authenticating the server needs so much time. when i connect using my mac (10.6), the login prompt comes up quickly, but when entered the credentials, it takes like 10sec "Connecting..." till the share comes up.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Most appletalk authentication and connection initiation issues are related to the network interface duplex settings.  The issue is usually found where one Ethernet side is set to 100 full and the other side is set to auto-negotiate.  This can be remedied by either forcing both sides or setting both sides to auto-negotiate.  These settings can be found on the server side, client side, or on any of the switch trunk lines in between.

Answer (score 1):

There's some talk that the problem is that the DHX2 authentication module (required for Leopard+) regenerates the Mersenne primes every time you try to log in (which can take quite a while, especially on slower machines!).  2.2 theoretically fixes that (by generating them just once at startup), but it's only just been officially released and I haven't tried it yet.